# On-Device Google Billing V3 and Google Play Developer API subscription data don't match

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

I've been working on android app with in-app subscriptions.
As the subscriptions should allow cross-platform access, we're storing and refreshing the subscriptions on our own servers as well, using the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions)

But I'm getting different/contradictory result:

on-device:

```
{
  "packageName": "com.redacted.package",
  "productId": "quarterly_plan",
  "purchaseTime": 1491390720784,
  "purchaseState": 0,
  "purchaseToken": "redacted-token",
  "autoRenewing": true
}
```

server api: (Google API explorer and NodeJS client lib return the same data)

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "startTimeMillis": "1491390720784",
  "expiryTimeMillis": "1491427785807",
  "autoRenewing": false,
  "priceCurrencyCode": "TWD",
  "priceAmountMicros": "1120000000",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "developerPayload": "",
  "cancelReason": 0
}
```

Note that above is the exact same purchase token. It is a test-license purchase, but it still seems odd to me.
I haven't manually canceled the subscription (which cancelReason: 0 indicates) and I still have the subscription in my "subscriptions" tab in the Google Play App.

Does anyone have an explanation or faced similar issues ?

Comment: Can i have parameters names which you have used with Server API ?

Comment: @ViramP not sure what you mean by that ?
I'm using the [NodeJS googleapis client v18.0](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and the [Google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidpublisher/v2/androidpublisher.purchases.subscriptions.get). I can't give you the package name or purchase token (It wouldn't be of any use for you without authentication on my project anyways)